# How do I read Linux Environment Variables within Wine?

Tags: environment-variables, config, wine

I have some native Linux apps and some Wine apps that need to store configuration. I want to write the config data to ~/.config/some/path. But I'm not sure how to get to that directory from Wine.

I tried reading the Linux environment variables, but it doesn't work:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ echo $HOME
/home/user
user@ubuntu:~$ wine cmd
Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134

Z:\home\user\.wine>echo %HOME%
%HOME%
```

I also tried using `~`, but that just creates a directory named `~` in the current working directory.

Any advice? How can I access the ~/.config directory from within a wine app?

Comment: Which subset of the UNIX filesystem WINE makes available to processes is configurable -- it's possible for WINE to be set up in such a way that the user's home directory can't be accessed at all. Whereas if you wanted it to make `~` available as something like `H:`, it could be set up for that too. Heck, you could directly map `~/.config/some/path` itself to a drive letter if you wanted.

Comment: Also, WINE _does_ pass environment variables through in general, though `HOME` is liable to be a special case. If you `export MYHOME=$HOME` before starting wine (note, it needs to actually start wineserver to pick up a change), you _should_ see that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the info. I know Wine is configurable, but I'm hoping for a way to do it using the default configuration to make setup easier for my users. It would it be best to use an installer to export the extra variables that Wine needs?

Comment: I'd probably aim for a wrapper more than an installer. If you have the program started through your own wrapper, for that matter, you can direct wine to use a completely different configuration _when running your individual program_ than it uses for anything/everything else.